# What is this form of 'notation' called?

Tags: matrices, elementary-set-theory, notation

I was reading some of Max Tegmark's lecture materials and I found this little thing. Is there a name for it? 
[image: ???]
Specifically, I am talking about $S_1$ R $S_2$ & $S_1$ R $S_2$ and the matrix.

Is there a name for this sort of notation?

Answer (score 3):

The graph is the Hasse diagram for the relation $R$ (which is a partial order), and the matrix is the adjacency matrix for the graph.

Answer (score 1):

$S_1$ is in relation with $S_2$.

Comment: But what is that actually *called*. I get what it means.

Comment: check wikipedia "relation" ;)

Comment: or you mean "ordered graph"?

Comment: Not that. I was just wondering what it is called. Thank you very much.

Comment: If it helps, you than think of it as $f(S_1) = S_2$ and $f(S_1) = S_3$. Since it is not a function but a relation, this notation I've mentioned is usually avoided.